# Log executed shell command from snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I'd like to save the shell command executed by each snakemake job to a log file.

With `--printshellcmds` I can print to stdout the shell commands as they are submitted but I would like to save them to individual files. For example, this script:

```
samples= ['a', 'b', 'c']

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{sample}.done', sample= samples),

rule do_stuff:
    output:
        '{sample}.done'
    shell:
        """
        echo {wildcards.sample} > {output}
        """
```

will execute the 3 jobs:

```
echo a > a.done
echo c > c.done
echo b > b.done
```

I'd like to save each of these to a separate file named after a wildcard (or whatever). Like:

```
rule do_stuff:
    output:
        '{sample}.done'
    log_shell:               < save shell command
        '{sample}.cmd.log'   <
    shell:
        """
        echo {wildcards.sample} > {output}
        """
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While fiddling with other [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50042226/output-log-file-to-cluster-option), I came up with this solution. Combine the `run`directive with the `shell` function to first write the command to file and then execute the command itself. Example:

```
rule do_stuff:
    output:
        '{sample}.done'
    log:
        cmd= 'my/logs/{sample}.log'
    run:
        cmd= """
        echo hello > {output}
        """

        shell("sort --version > {log.cmd} || true") # Log version
        shell("cat <<'EOF' >> {log.cmd}" + cmd)     # Log command

        shell(cmd) # Exec command
```

For each `{sample}` you get a file `my/logs/{sample}.log` that looks like this:

```
sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

echo hello > a.done
```

This does the trick. However, it makes the code more cluttered and you effectively lose the `--printshellcmds` option.

Comment: I don't think this works with the `conda` directive either?

Comment: @winni2k I don't see why it shouldn't work with a conda directive (but I haven't tried it). I'm just putting the shell command in a variable as a string, write it to the file `{log.cmd}` and execute it using `shell`. So nothing particularly unusual...