# Output log file to cluster option

Tags: logging, cluster-computing, slurm, snakemake

I'm submitting jobs to `slurm/sbatch` via `snakemake`. I'm trying to send the log from sbatch to a file in the same directory tree of the rule's output.

For example, this works:

```
rm -rf foo
snakemake -s test.smk --jobs 1 --cluster "sbatch --output log.txt"
```

but it fails (*i.e.* slurm job status is FAILED) if I try:

```
rm -rf foo
snakemake -s test.smk --jobs 1 --cluster "sbatch --output {output}.log"
```

presumably, because `{output}` points to `foo/bar/` which does not exist. But snakemake should have created it, right?

This is `test.smk`:

```
rule all:
    output:
        'foo/bar/done.txt'
    shell:
        """
        touch {output}
        """
```

So, how can I send logs to a directory tree not yet existing but created by the rule? (I'm reluctant in including code in the snakefile that create dirs in anticipation).

```
snakemake -v
4.8.0
```

Comment: I just tested your code with LSF cluster and snakemake v4.8.0, and it creates log file `foo/bar/done.txt.log` as expected.

Comment: @JeeYem thanks for sharing that. Unfortunately, I cannot be more specific about the reason for the job failing as I don't get any log from slurm, even if I redirect the error log to a different file. Also, snakemake doesn't tell me anything since it hangs on the failing job (see also https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/427/detect-killed-jobs-in-cluster-environment). Anyway, it seems my code is fine but there is some odd interaction between snakemake and slurm (at least on my system...)

Comment: "even if I redirect the error log to a different file" - you mean even if explicitly defined, for example, `log.txt` doesn't get saved properly?

Comment: @JeeYem Yes, the error log file is not created even if it points to a valid and existing directory. This is due to slurm/sbatch (or its configuration on my system, I don't know). For example: `sbatch -o /foo/out.log -e err.log --wrap "echo 'done'"` fails and `err.log` is not created at all in the current dir (which is writable of course.)